# How do I get specific line of HTML from certain text parameter in Python Requests/Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to scrape a website that has shoes. Each shoe size has a unique "variant" id. I need to figure out how to get that id based on what shoe size I want. An example of the HTML of the site is:

```
    <label for="variant_id_104685">43</label>
```

In this example, the shoe size is "43" I need to get that variant_id_104685 segment without already knowing it in advanced. In other words the input would be asking for size 43 and the output would return that variant id.

How should I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `label` element by text and then extract the `for` attribute value:

```
size = "43"
soup.find(attrs={"for": True}, text=size)["for"]
```

Demo:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = '<label for="variant_id_104685">43</label>'

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [4]: size = "43"

In [5]: soup.find(attrs={"for": True}, text=size)["for"]
Out[5]: 'variant_id_104685'
```

---

Note that the `{"for": True}` here helps to take into account only the `label` elements that have `for` attribute defined. You can usually have a more concise way to ask for presence of an attribute using a keyword argument like `soup.find(attribute_name=True)`, but in this case `for` is a reserved keyword and having something like `soup.find(text=size, for=True)["for"]` would result into a syntax error.